# The environment variable ROS_HOSTNAME

Tags: ros, nodes, ros-hostname, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two nodes which communicate with each other with the help of the master. Each node has a specific host name, and this value is stored in node environment variable ROS_HOSTNAME. I want to learn the value of the environment variable ROS_HOSTNAME of my nodes.

How can I learn them ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314565/the-environment-variable-ros_hostname/) by [gktg1514](https://answers.ros.org/users/37700/gktg1514/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2019-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rosnode info` command will show the URI (including the hostname) that other nodes will use to reach that node.

(the node's hostname defaults to the computer's hostname, but can be overridden by the `ROS_HOSTNAME` and `ROS_IP` environment variables)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2